# LINQ query multiple conditions

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I need to have multiple conditions in my LINQ.

I have a database with id, Name, and pID. For instance, the data would be:

```
id=1 | Name='A1' | pID = 0
id=2 | Name='A2' | pID = 0
id=3 | Name='A3' | pID = 0
id=4 | Name='A2' | pID = 5
```

In this case the pID=0 is the defaults data. However, when someone edit a specific Name, a new record is inserted for this name with a new pID. My problem is when I try to query this data. I need to get all the Names for a specific pID and the defaults, but I can't have the same names.
I want a query that return the ids 1, 4, and 3.

I tried it:

```
int id = 5;

var test= db.MyTable.Where(a => a.pID == id).ToList();
```

It only returns the row with id=4

```
int id = 5;

var test= db.MyTable.Where(a => a.pID == id || a.pID == 0).ToList();
```

It return everything.

Does anyone know how to query it using LINQ?

Comment: And what is it that it should return? You only have data with `pID = 5` and default

Comment: Sorry, it should return: id=1 | Name='A1' | pID = 0   -----
id=3 | Name='A3' | pID = 0   -----
id=4 | Name='A2' | pID = 5

Comment: Add a select `.Select(t => new { t.id, t.Name, t.pID })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to distinct `Name` by considering `Pid`. You can try like this;

```
  int id = 5;
  var records = db.MyTable.Where(x => x.pID == 0 || x.pID == id).OrderByDescending(x => x.pID).GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Comment: In this case it will group by "Name", but if I have 2 rows with the same name, I would like to get the one where pID = id not pID = 0

Comment: The query will perform it as expected.

Comment: Great. Will it happens because the OrderByDescending(x => x.pID) ?

Comment: I have one problem... Because I'm using MySQL, it generates me an error in production when I use FirstOrDefault(). Is there a way to do this LINQ without FirstOrDefault()?

Comment: What is the error ? You can use First() with DefaultIfEmpty()

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you

```
var listOfIds = from x in db.MyTable
                     group x by x.Name
                  into groups
                     select groups.OrderByDescending(p => p.pID).First();
```

Comment: But I need a list